# removing error query during commit

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have postgresql db which i am updating with around 100000 records. I use session.merge() to insert/update each record and i do a commit after every 1000 records.

```
i=0
for record in records:
    i+=1
    session.merge(record)
    if i%1000 == 0:
        session.commit()
```

This code works fine. In my database i have a table with a UNIQUE field and there are some duplicated records that i insert into it. A error is thrown when this happens, saying the field is not unique. Since i am inserting 1000 records at a time, a rollback will not help me to skip these records. is there any way i can skip the session.merge() for the duplicate records (other than parsing through all the records to find the duplicate records of course)?

Comment: I suspect that "parsing through all the records to find the duplicate records" is the only way while preserving the semantics of ACID and UNIQUE. On the other hand, reading out the unique id field for 100'000 and checking for duplicates in your client code would be much faster than the alternatives and could make the difference between "tolerably slow" and "way too slow" assuming that the merging table isn't changing much underneath you.

Comment: @msw yeah, im stuck between a rock and a hard place. the merging table is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the option which works best for me because the number of records with duplicate unique keys is minimal.

```
def update_exception(records, i, failed_records):
    failed_records.append(records[i]['pk'])
    session.rollback()
    start_range = int(round(i/1000,0) * 1000)
    for index in range(start_range, i+1):
        if records[index]['pk'] not in failed_records:
            ins_obj = Model()
            try:
                session.merge(ins_obj)
            except:
                failed_records.append(json_data[table_name][index-1]['pk'])
                pass
```

Say, if i hit an error at 2375 I store the primary key 'pk' for the 2375 record in failed_records and then i recommit from 2000 to 2375.  It seems much faster than doing commits one by one.

Comment: Again, this is a solution that i found specific to my needs. I dont encounter many records with duplicate unique field values. Any ideas on how to optimize it are welcome

Answer (score 3):

I think you already know this, but let's start out with a piece of dogma: you specified that the field needs to be unique, so you have to let the database check for uniqueness or deal with the errors from not letting that happen.

Checking for uniqueness:

```
if value not in database:
    session.add(value)
session.commit()
```

Not checking for uniqueness and catching the exception.

```
try:
    session.add(value)
    session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
```

The first one has a race condition. I tend to use the second pattern.

Now, bringing this back to your actual issue, if you want to assure uniqueness on a column in the database then obviously you're going to have to either let the db assure itself of the loaded value's actual uniqueness, or let the database give you an error and you handle it.

That's obviously a lot slower than adding 100k objects to the session and just committing them all, but that's how databases work.

You might want to consider massaging the data which you are loading OUTSIDE the database and BEFORE attempting to load it, to ensure uniqueness. That way, when you load it you can drop the need to check for uniqueness. Pretty easy to do with command line tools if for example you're loading from csv or text files.

Answer (score 2):

you can get at a "partial rollback" using SAVEPOINT, which SQLAlchemy exposes via begin_nested().   You could do it just like this:

```
for i, record in enumerate(records):
    try:
        with session.begin_nested():
            session.merge(record)
    except:
        print "Skipped record %s" % record
    if not i % 1000:
        session.commit()
```

notes for the above:

1. in python, we *never* do the "i = i+1" thing.  use `enumerate()`.
2. `with session.begin_nested():` is the same as saying `begin_nested()`, then `commit()` if no exception, or `rollback()` if so.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider writing a function along the lines of [this example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) from the PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: i dont quite understand. how do i do it in sqlalchemy? can i access this function in sqlalchemy or do i run it as an sql script? (im a noob at python, postgres and sqlalchemy)

Comment: I don't know sqlalchemy, but I assume that you would us another tool (like psql or pgadmin) to create the function, and reference the function from within sqlalchemy.

Comment: im not sure i know how to do that. can u guide me on how i should do it?